# ORA-01017 error in sqlplus 12.1, can connect with same credentials in other applications

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, ora-01017

I have SQL*Plus 12.1 installed on Fedora 19 trying to connect to an Oracle 11g database. I installed the instantclient RPM packages (basic, devel, sqlplus) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html). I can successfully connect to other Oracle databases using SQL*Plus, so I know I have a working installation of the software. However, when I try to connect to this particular database, I get this error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Here's my tnsnames.ora file (with the host and port obfuscated out):

```
PSPRODDB =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = #HOST-ADDR)(PORT = #PORT-NUM))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = PSPRODDB)
 )
)
```

My TNS_ADMIN environment variable is set to the path of my tnsnames.ora file.

The command I'm running to connect:

```
sqlplus username/password@PSPRODDB
```

After pressing enter, it hangs on the version and copyright info for about 2-3 seconds before giving me the ORA-01017 error.

I know I have the username and password correctly typed in because I copied and pasted it from another application that successfully connects to the database.

**Edit**

I've looked at the log.xml file (in `C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\diag\tnslsnr\test\listener\alert\log.xml`), and found that there a few entries that show I'm talking to the correct listener. Here's an example of the log entry, but obfuscated for possibly sensitive info:

```
<msg time='2013-11-25T09:54:08.530-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='PSTEST100-50'
 host_addr='*my address*'>
 <txt>25-NOV-2013 09:54:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PSPRODDB)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=*localhost*)(USER=njones))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=*addr*)(PORT=38906)) * establish * PSPRODDB * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

I've also since tried changing the *SERVICE_NAME* element in my tnsnames.ora file to *SID*, with no difference.

Surrounding my password with quotes didn't fix the problem either.

Could there be a version problem? I'm using instantclient and sqlplus version 12.1, but the database is version 11.2.

**Edit 2**

Well, it's official. I'm an idiot, and that's what caused the error. I was typing in the wrong password, and I guess whatever I was copy-pasting was wrong too.

Comment: Is it really the same database ? No case differences in password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ideas, in order of likelihood of causing this problem:

1) If your password starts with a non-alphabetic character, surround password with quotes: `user/"password"@service`  (note, GUI apps e.g. TOAD and SQLDeveloper don't require quotes).

<strike>2) Run</strike>

```
> tnsping service
```

And confirm your output matches the tnsnames.ora entry you think you are using

3) On server, run (or ask dba to run)

```
> lsnrctl status
```

Confirm that the service listed in your tnsnames.ora is being directed to the proper database.

EDIT: Saw Nathan's question, thought, "hmm - weird, I use tnsping all the time to validate client installs, why the heck wouldn't it be included in instantclients???"  Asked Google, and lo-and-behold, it turns out TNSPING is pretty much useless.  The ONLY think it checks is that host is reachable and that a tnslistener is running on the specified port (which you could easily check with telnet).  H/T to "BillyVerreynne" on Oracle forums: https://forums.oracle.com/message/10561771

Yay, I learned something today! :-)  On that note, I'll personally be switching to SQLPlus for deep-dive checking of TNS specifications, and recommend everyone reading this do the same.  As Nathan already posted above, issues with SQLPlus connection attempts can be reviewed in $ORACLE_BASE/diag/tnslsnr/test/listener/alert/log.xml.

Comment: My installation of SQL*Plus and instantclient did not include a utility called `tnsping`. How can I install it on a Fedora 19 Linux system? My google skills are failing to find anything.

Comment: I installed the instantclient RPM packages (basic, devel, sqlplus) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)

Answer (score 2):

ORA-01017 is pretty clear.  It means that you got either the username or password wrong, or possibly that you're not *really* connecting to the database that you think you're connecting to.

There's really not much more to say.  Double check your connect descriptor, and make sure you didn't mistype the username or password.

Answer (score -1):

In your sqlnet.ora set

```
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = support
```

See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/sqlnet.htm) for descriptions of what these do.  You'll get files in $ORACLE_HOME/network/trace that include information on the client connections.
My guess is that you're having trouble talking to the TNS listener from your client machine, or something like that.

Unfortunately, if the problem is too close to the server, the client tracing may not help so much.  Since this is a prod database that may be a bit tricky to diagnose.  If you do have an Oracle support contract, they're really good at resolving this sort of thing.

I realize this is not a complete answer, but I suspect from that trace you'll find other more interesting errors.  ORA-01017 tends to be the generic error that the networking layer passes up to the higher layer, and the useful errors are a layer down in the trace.

Comment: I have to disagree.  The user is getting ORA-01017, "invalid username/password; logon denied", not ORA-00017, "session requested to set trace event".  Further, I've never seen an actual occurrence of ORA-00017.  It seems to be an internal error.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak I typoed the error number in my answer. What I say is consistent with my experience of invalid username/password especially with a hang as described.  Other TNS failures have in my experienced surfaced that way.

Comment: Sam, TNS failures should raise a TNS-xxxxx error, not an ORA-xxxxx error.  I don't think an ORA-01017 will show any error in a client side SQL*Net trace.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak Yes, it's possible that you'll end up needing a server-side trace.  And if tnsping or checking the config files solves things, great.  But tracing first client and then looking at the server eventually will succeed.